# CSS: translate property on a gif

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I am trying to get my gif to move towards the right side and then back to its original position. I have the keyframes set and everything, but my images is still not moving. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```css
.mushroom {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  animation-name: move-right;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

@keyframes move-right {
  0% {
    transform: translate (0, 0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate (50px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate (100px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate (150px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate (200px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="mushroom2">
    <img src="css/images/mush.gif" alt="orange mushroom" class="mushroom">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Take out the spaces between `translate` and the values, ie `translate(50px, 0);` I'm voting to close this question as **simple typographical error**.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing left property instead.

```css
.mushroom {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  animation: moveright 5s infinite;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes moveright {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="mushroom2">
    <img src="css/images/mush.gif" alt="orange mushroom" class="mushroom">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response and help. Using the left property finally got it to move!

Comment: As a future note, try [not to answer off-topic questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions). :)

Comment: whats an off topic ques! its not marked off topic, also not marked as duplicate. i didnt find it off topic and the ques has 2 upvotes. so i think i can answer it. But thanks for the link, will not answer off topic questions in future. but this ques was not off topic according to me!

Comment: I don't think it's a big deal, just providing a bit of information. As you can see in the [what's on topic (#2)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), *questions that are the result of a simple typographical error are considered off-topic*. Being that OP's question was the result of one missing space, I'd lump this into that category. But you do as you feel is right - as long as OP gets the solution to their problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is as simple as removing white spaces from between `translate` and the opening `(` at each transform in your CSS animation:

```
@keyframes move-right {
  0% {
    /* transform: translate (0px, 0px); - white space between translate and ( causes syntax error in your CSS */
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(50px, 0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(100px, 0px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(150px, 0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(200px, 0px);
  }
}
```

The white space basically causes a syntax error, which causes parsing of the CSS and animation to fail. This is why you're not seeing any movement/animation.

Hope that helps!

Comment: As a future note, try [not to answer off-topic questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions). :)